# Verificar se email já existe com codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Quero verificar se um e-mail já existe no banco de dados. Estou fazendo o seguinte.

```
$this->load->database();
      $query = $this->db->get_where('usuario', array('email'));
      $result = $query->result_array();
      if(count($result) > 0) {
        echo "email existe";

      } else { echo "email não existe";}
```

Só que sempre me retorna que o e-mail já existe mesmo eu digitando um diferente. Aonde está meu erro? Ou estou fazendo errado e tem outro jeito?

Comment: Use o sistema de validação do Codeigniter. Use a validação `is_unique`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensei na seguinte solução:

```
$this->db->select('email');
$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
$retorno = $this->db->get('usuario')->num_rows();

if($retorno > 0 ){
    echo "este e-mail já está cadastrado";
} else { 
    echo "este e-mail está disponível";
}
```